# Hibernate: Custom ID generator needs to persist entity

Tags: hibernate, session, id-generation

I'm implementing a custom Id generator for Hibernate. In my generate-method I need to read from another table and modify data on it. That's (about) the way I would do it:

```
session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(...)...;
criteria.uniqueResult();
...
session.save(...);
transaction.commit();
```

That works fine, but how can I use it in my Generator. The generate-method gets a `SessionImplementor`, not a `Session`. How can I persist an entity with it?

```
public class MyGenerator implements IdentifierGenerator
{
    @Override
    public Serializable generate(final SessionImplementor session, final Object object) throws HibernateException
    {
        ???
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be quite simple:

```
Session session = ( Session ) sessionImplementor;
```